# How do I print the value of a dictionary in color with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, colors, ansi-escape

I know how I can print the statements in color: `print("\033[32m Hello! \033[0m")` or with Rich `print("[green]Hello![/green]")`.

But how do I print a dictionary's value(s) in color when it comes from a list? Or a dictionary's value(s) in general?

EX:

```
dict = {
        "greetings" : ["hello", "bonjour"],
        "goodbyes" : ["adios", "4"]
    }
newList = ["hola", "barev"]
dict.update({"greetings" : newList})
print(dict["greetings"][0])
print(dict)
```

The two above print statements would print in black, how would I make it print in green? What would I need to do? What packages/libraries would I need to download if needed?

Comment: You shouldn't use `dict` or any other builtin name as variable name. Ideally, use something meaningful, maybe `words` in this case.

Comment: I use colorama.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that there are Python reserved words like `dict` and `sum` that should be avoided as variables. You could try to print with f-strings:

```
dic = {
        "greetings": ["hello", "bonjour"],
        "goodbyes": ["adios", "4"]
    }
newList = ["hola", "barev"]
dic.update({"greetings": newList})

hola = dic["greetings"][0]
print(f"\033[32m{hola}\033[0m")

print(f"\033[32m{dic}\033[0m")
```

Or this:

```
print("\033[32m{}\033[0m".format(hola))

print("\033[32m{}\033[0m".format(dic))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from termcolor import colored

print(colored(dict, 'green'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$ pip install pygments
```

From the [FAQ](https://pygments.org/faq/):

> pygmentize -f html /path/to/file.py

will get you a long way toward rendering
those print'ed or pretty [pp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pp)'ed data structures
in glorious technicolor.

Answer (score 0):

With rich, you can do

```py
d = {
        "greetings" : ["hello", "bonjour"],
        "goodbyes" : ["adios", "4"]
}
console.print(d, style="green", highlight=False)
console.print(d["greetings"][0], style="green", highlight=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

check out the package `rich` that does a fantastic job of "pretty printing" objects in color...

You can pip install it, and then just override the default print command:

```
from rich import print

a = {1: 'dog', 2: 'cat', 3:'bird'}
b = ['horse', 'goat', 'cheetah']

print(a)
print(b)
```

[image]